# Android lengthen sound clips

Tags: android, audio

I have created a number of sound clips using Audacity and have them exported them as .OGG files into the soundpool. Some of the longer clips stop early though. Is there a set length for each clip in the soundpool? Is it something I can extend?

Here is my SoundManager:

```
package com.androidbook.ufgsoundboard;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;



public class SoundManager {

    private  SoundPool mSoundPool; 
    private  HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap; 
    private  AudioManager  mAudioManager;
    private  Context mContext;
    public static final int maxSounds = 1;

    public SoundManager()
    {

    }

    public void initSounds(Context theContext) { 
         mContext = theContext;
         mSoundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0); 
         mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
         mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);         
    } 

    public void addSound(int Index,int SoundID)
    {
        mSoundPoolMap.put(Index, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));

    }

    public void playSound(int index) { 

         int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
         mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f); 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to save my original sound clips in Audacity as 11025 HZ 16-bit OGG files. This allows the clips to be as long as I want.